# How can I get live input box field value by Ajax in same page to assign a php veriable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I would like to assign input box field value as a php variable in a same page when any keypress/keyup event is happen.
The input box is as following,

```
<input type="search" id="searchbox" class="inputbox-findtag" name="keyword" placeholder="Search tag...">
```

I would like to assign the input box field value with live(i.e, on keyup/keypress/...) as a php variable in a same page that is look like,

```
$field_value = [input box value]
```

To do this I have already used jQuery-Ajax that is look like below,

```
$("#searchbox").on('keyup',function () {
    var key = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
        url:'fetch.php',
        type:'GET',
        data:'keyword='+key,

        success:function (data) {
          $("#rsql").html(data);
        }
    });

});
```

And the fetch.php file is below,

```
 if($_GET['keyword'] && !empty($_GET['keyword']))
 {
      $keyword = $_GET['keyword'];
      echo $keyword;
 }
```

I have already got the input box value by keyup. But how can I assign this value as a php variable $field_value that I have declared previous.

If you have any other idea to get live input box field value in same page to assign a php variable then you can share it.

Comment: By assigning the value of textbox to Php variable what you want to do ?

Comment: By the way you can not do that kind of stuff. You can make JS variable from PHP variable, but you can not assign PHP variable from JS variable.

Comment: Is it possible to do it by ajax?

Comment: Can u help me how can i do that?

Comment: try ajax. but do you want to assign the input value on each keypress?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36026695/4248328   And    http://stackoverflow.com/a/36026828/4248328

Answer (score 0):

As Per [Assign jquery value to php variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36026673/assign-jquery-value-to-php-variable/36026695#36026695)

> You simply cannot do that, you need to understand the difference
>   between client/server side programming, you cannot assign Javascript
>   value to PHP variable, yea but you can assign PHP value to your
>   javascript.
>
> You can use cookies to achieve this.
>
> In Javascript:
>
> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">
>     document.cookie = "var1=1";
> </script>
> ```
>
> And in PHP
>
> ```
> <?php 
>    $phpVar =  $_COOKIE['var1'];
>    echo $phpVar;
> ?>
> ```